# How to debug angular protractor tests in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor, webstorm

There is a way to run and debug protractor web-tests in WebStorm.
I just want to share [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/133) answer here

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. Get the node path (Type `which node` in your terminal)
2. In the WebStorm: Click on "**Edit configurations**" - the dropdown to the left of the "**Run**" button (green arrow like a "play" button)
3. Click on the "Add button" (green **+**) to add a new Node configuration. Select "**Node.js**"
4. Fill the params:

**Node interpreter**: Full path to Node.js (from step 1)

**Working directory**: home directory for the protractor tests.

**Javascript file**: Full path to `node_modules/protractor/lib/cli.js`

**Application parameters**: Full path to `protractor-conf.js`

Now you be able to run and debug tests by clicking on "Run" or "Debug" buttons on the top of IDE

Comment: Hmm.. may be few steps didn't clear? Please give more info, I'll try to help you

Comment: yeah, didn't work for me either; posted at length about it here- http://stackoverflow.com/q/21992414/537913

Comment: In my case it doesn't start the tests if I use "Debug" (bug icon) and it starts the tests if I use "Run" (play icon), but it doesn't stop anywhere.

Comment: Looks like with doing the "Debug" option (bug icon), it adds --debug-brk=62532 --nolazy to the node command line.

Comment: An additional thing, in this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLMyI7QKcwg) looks like web storm identifies the breakpoint with the usual "tick" inside, whereas in my case, it doesn't.

Comment: I think it should be **protractor.conf.js** *not* protractor-conf.js.

Comment: In my case - it "runs" fine. while debugging, it gives error "Process finished with exit code 139" I am on Mac.

Comment: In my case the javascript file is the following: node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor

Answer (score 15):

It works! Here are my settings

[image]

Comment: this only works for me if I add '--harmony' to Node parameters

Comment: Path is now node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js

Comment: The full path on my Mac was /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js

Comment: Also make sure to keep the ng serve running, the web storm just runs the protractor test doesn't starts the server unlike command line.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same problems described by comments to S.Panfilov's answer, i.e., running protractor in WebStorm worked fine, but the debugging process got stuck somewhere.

The issue is described [here](http://heidesangular.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/debugging-protractor-tests-in-webstorm-2/). It was occurring under Mac OS X with version 0.20.1 of protractor, and node v0.10.26.

The problem is solved in **version 0.22**.

- Update protractor to the latest version (>= 0.22) using npm
- Run again: *node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update*
- In WebStorm configure 'Your Protractor Conf' as described by S.Panfilov in his answer
- Set breakpoints in your protractor test file (watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLMyI7QKcwg) first)
- Launch "Run > Debug 'Your Protractor Conf'" from WebStorm
- Enjoy debugging

Answer (score 2):

For mac OSX:
[image]
on the left you can see tests folder structure

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me. It was looking for the protractor.conf.js in the wrong folder. Had to look up a couple dirs.

**Application parameters: ../../protractor.conf.js**

Answer (score 1):

Like some of the other responses here, I found that I could run in release but couldn't run in Debug and it would just hang at some point.  I found that I had the conf file set to target two browsers and it seems that this was too much for the debugger and it would hang without any more info.  Targeting only a single browser fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

By the way **if you need to pass additional parameters** here is the configuration you need

- Select **‘Node.js’** configuration from the list
- Name: ‘Protractor’
- Node interpreter: ‘C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe’
- Node parameters: ‘’
- Working directory:
- JavaScript file: ‘~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js’
- **Application parameters, this is where you specify path to your conf, relatively to working directory^ and then parameters like this**: ‘e2e/settings/configs/protractor.custom.conf.js --baseUrl="https://stage.mysite.com" --params.login="testuser" --params.password="test_USER00"’
- Environment variables: ‘’

This config works great in my project, where we solely rely on async/await syntax