# debugging protactor (with / without webstorm)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, debugging, protractor

So I'm starting out with protractor, and I want to debug my test code:

```
describe('stuff', function(){

it('should find the specs item, and its empty', function(){
    browser.debugger();
    gotoHome();
    var allItems = element.all('li in model.tags');
    var specsDashboardElement;
    for (var i=0 ; i < allItems.length; ++i) {
        var elem = allItems[i];
        var text = elem.findElement(by.css('.li-title').getText()); // does this even work?? dunno
        if (text == "Specs")
            specsDashboardElement = elem;
    }

    expect(specsDashboardElement.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

});
```

});

I've followed [these instructions](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md), but this is the output I see on the node.js debugger console:

> D:\src\apps\j1-test.module>protractor debug conf.js
>   < debugger listening on port 5858
>   connecting... ok
>   break in C:\Users\j\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js:7
>     5  * Values from command line options override values from the config.
>     6  */
>     7 'use strict';
>     8
>     9 // Coffee is required here to enable config files written in coffee-script.
>   debug> cont
>   < ------------------------------------
>   < PID: 9756 (capability: chrome #1)
>   < ------------------------------------
>   < debugger listening on port 5858
>   debug>

and that's it. no matter how many types I type 'cont', nothing happens.
I've tried following the instructions for debugging in WebStorm, with much the same result (output on the WebStorm debug console:

> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=2259 C:\Users\j\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js
>    conf.js
>   debugger listening on port 2259
>       PID: 2708 (capability: chrome #1)
>   debugger listening on port 2259

).

I'm using node 0.10.26 (64 bit) on windows 8

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Did you try typing just `c`? "This uses the node debugger. Enter `c` to start execution and continue after the breakpoint."

Comment: yes, i did (from what i understand, 'c' is just shorthand for 'cont')

Comment: And did you try to set breakpoint with node `debugger` statement instead of `browser.debugger()`? (to see if there's a difference). There are some issues about debugging on GitHub: [issue #363](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/363), [issue #517](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/517). Does it seem related?

Comment: unfortunately doesn't seem related. 
Interestingly, You can see in the video linked in issue #363, that the output he got on the webstorm console was `using the selinium server at...`, which I didn't get (see my question)

Comment: hm... debugging apart, protractor is working fine on your computer?

Comment: yup- some of their samples and also a few i've written myself

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48339/discussion-between-glepretre-and-sjhonny)

Comment: mm.. could it be related to the fact i've god node 64bit installed? (using win8 machine)

Comment: I have the same problem. Windows 7, protractor Version 0.19.0, node v0.10.25. Generally protractor is working.

Comment: @s.Daniel is it working now with 0.20.1? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was a Protractor issue, which should be fixed now:

"Fix is in - should be out next release. Thanks for your patience, everyone." - @juliemr

from [GitHub issue #552](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/552)

**EDIT:** Released in 0.20.0 version! (0.20.1 for Windows users). See [Protractor changelog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0200).