# where to go next with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

When I run protractor config.js

I get this output:

```
------------------------------------
PID: 43900 (capability: firefoxANY #1)
------------------------------------

Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

but nothing happens and nothing times out. How can I debug what is going on? I can navigate to /wd/hub and see a session but can't get any information from there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [debugging protactor (with / without webstorm)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992414/debugging-protactor-with-without-webstorm)

Comment: Does your `config.js` have a `specs` section that includes the spec source files?

Comment: will try upgrading protractor per other ticket? I thought I was on the latest but not sure. My experience is similar - I start debugging and get stuck in cli.js never really getting any information I can make use of. I usually just keep hitting n to go to next breakpoint but yea nothing I can see to help me. I do have section in config with appropriate paths to my specs.

Comment: upgrading protractor worked in the sense that it had a better error message of why it failed. I was able to use this information to get it running.

Comment: What was wrong? (just curious)