# how to debug protractor with webstorm 8?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, webstorm

Trying to debug protractor on webstorm 8 . Followed these instructions: [How to debug angular protractor tests in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137109/how-to-debug-angular-protractor-tests-in-webstorm)

When I click the debug icon i get this error message:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 8.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=3803 --nolazy c:\protractor\node_modules\protractor-tester\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js protractor.conf.js
debugger listening on port 3803

c:\protractor\node_modules\protractor-tester\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js:138
    throw new Error('You must specify either a seleniumAddress, ' +
          ^
Error: You must specify either a seleniumAddress, seleniumServerJar, or saucelabs account.
    at run (c:\protractor\node_modules\protractor-tester\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js:138:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\protractor\node_modules\protractor-tester\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js:265:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:497:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

Process finished with exit code 8
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe your protractor config file is missing the selenium address. Are you able to run the tests from the command line?

Comment: Can you post your protractor.conf.js file?

Answer (score 1):

Your protractor.conf.js should look like:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
    ...
}
```