# Debug Protractor Test case in IntelliJ using Intellij JavaScript debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, selenium, intellij-idea, protractor

I have a question on debugging Protractor script in Intellij Idea 14.
I did set up Dubuger configuration per this doc: protractor/docs/debugging.md and tried to debug my code by putting break-point against console.log to check value of lblInvalidLoginMsg object:

```
it('should do something', function() {
  txtEmail.sendKeys("aaa@asd.com");
  txtPassword.sendKeys("aaaaa");
  btnSignIn.click();
  lblInvalidLoginMsg.getAttribute('value').then(function(){
    console.log("hello");
  })

  expect(lblInvalidLoginMsg.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('Blah Blah');
});
```

The problem is that debugger is showing no values when breakpoint is encountered. Debugger watch just shows me list of available methods i can apply against the object like `getText()`, `getID()` etc but no values that are expected.

Console output gives something like:

```
‌‌lblInvalidLoginMsg.getId()
‌ElementFinder
‌‌lblInvalidLoginMsg.isElementPresent();
‌webdriver.promise.Promise
```

Same goes with "Evaluate" feature. Is there something I am missing?

Updated: Added screenshot with my script in Debug mode + debug config + results from Protractor console.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Protractor heavily relies on a concept of promises. To see the actual values of the element's text or attributes, you need to resolve them using `then()`. Example:

```
element(by.id('#myId')).then(function(elm) {
    elm.getText().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);  // put a breakpoint here
    });  
});
```

or:

```
lblInvalidLoginMsg.getAttribute('value').then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);  // value here would contain an actual attribute value
});
```

Also, when the `protractor` is paused for debugging, you can use browser developer tools and call `protractor`'s injected client-side script commands, see:

- [Pausing to Debug](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#pausing-to-debug)

See also:

- [Debugging Protractor from WebStorm/IntelliJ](http://ng-learn.org/2014/02/Debugging_Protractor_from_WebStorm_Intellij/)
- [Pausing Protractor](http://ng-learn.org/2014/04/Pausing-Protractor/)
- [How to debug angular protractor tests in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137109/how-to-debug-angular-protractor-tests-in-webstorm)
- [Is Protractor debugging possible in WebStorm?](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/133)

Comment: Hi Alex,Thank you for your suggestions. I was able to get Protractor elementExplorer.js working but Debugging in IntelliJ Idea is still a mystery to me. I did set up breakpoint inside the then() statement per your suggestion but as before getting nothing but list of available element methods. I updated my original post with screenshot of my script in debug mode + debugger configuration + results from Protractor elementExplorer console.

Comment: @Vlad this is actually correct. You are getting an element instance with available methods. All of them would return a promise. For example, if you want to get the value of `getText()`, you need to write `elm.getText().then(function (text) { console.log(text); });`..