# How to debug protractor in Intellij?

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, protractor

In OSX, I have configured an Intellij 15 run/debug task as in this question:

[How to debug angular protractor tests in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137109/how-to-debug-angular-protractor-tests-in-webstorm)

It runs ok but debug doesn't work. It throws:

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=60144 --nolazy /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/cli.js /Users/XXXX/Workspace/frontend-test/config.js
Debugger listening on port 60144
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

Process finished with exit code 139
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Just add `--harmony` parameter to "Node parameters" in the Run/Debug Configuration window.