# Protractor - debugging in webstorm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, debugging, protractor

I tried to conffigurate protractor debuggin in my webstorm.
here is my configuration as mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137109/how-to-debug-angular-protractor-tests-in-webstorm):

[image: Protractor config]

This is the protractor.conf:

```
/*all the test files we want to add*/
  var specsArr = ['./js/init.js']; // init is mandatory for tests running

  /*for production*/
  //specsArr.push('*/*.e2e.js');

  /*for development*/
  specsArr.push('login/login.e2e.js');

  var config = {
    onPrepare: function(){
      global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      global.loggedIn = false;

      global.path = require('path');
      global.mock = require('protractor-http-mock');

      global.params = require("./js/e2e.params.js");
      global.utils = require('./js/e2e.utils.js');

      /*pages*/
      global.loginPage = require('./login/login.obj.js');
      global.dashboardPage =  require('./dashboard/dashboard.obj.js');
      global.sidebar = require('./sidebar/sidebar.obj.js');
      global.dataPathsPage = require('./datapath/datapaths.obj.js');
      global.createDataPathPage = require('./datapath/create-datapath.obj.js');
      global.singleDataPathPage = require('./datapath/single-datapath.obj.js');
      global.messagesPage = require('./messages/messages.obj.js');
      global.createMessagePage = require('./messages/create-message.obj.js');
      global.singleMessagePage = require('./messages/single-message.obj.js');
      global.usersPage = require('./users/users.obj.js');
      global.createUserPage = require('./users/create-user.obj.js');
      global.singleUserPage = singleUserPage = require('./users/single-user.obj.js');

      require('protractor-http-mock').config = {
        rootDirectory: __dirname, // default value: process.cwd()
        protractorConfig: 'protractor.conf'
      };
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
    chromeDriver: './activation/chromedriver.exe',
    seleniumServerJar: './activation/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar',
    specs: specsArr,
    mocks: {
      dir: 'mocks',
      default: []
    },
    capabilities: {
      'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true,
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
      isVerbose: true
    }
  };

  exports.config = config;
```

Now, when i click on the run button everything works perfectly. But, when i click debug i get the following output in the console:

[image]

Node version: v5.3.0

Protractor: v3.2.1

Comment: Could you try adding `--troubleshoot` command line argument and run it again? What is the output? Thanks.

Comment: still not working, just show the debug logs.

Comment: Of course it would not fix it magically - could you post the debug output into the question? Thanks.

Comment: They don't give any new information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by upgrade my node to 5.9.0.