# Protractor debug is failing in IntelliJ

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, protractor

I attempted to setup Intellij to debug my protractor test, but I'm getting an error which doesn't make sense to me.  (Not what the error is saying, but why it is telling me this.)

First, I followed the instructions here: [How to debug angular protractor tests in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137109/how-to-debug-angular-protractor-tests-in-webstorm)
including making sure I added `--harmony` to the Node parameters line.

I then attempted to run the script and got the following error message:

```
Error: No selenium server jar found at the specified location (/Users/x/Projects/v/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar). Check that the version number is up to date.
```

I then perform

```
$ webdriver-manager update
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.
```

I'm on a MacOS (El Capitan) using Intellij 2016.  Node is updated to 6.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the project-specific `webdriver-manager` binary:

```
$ cd /Users/x/Projects/v
$ node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: Right.  I was in ... Oh. I guess I was using the global manager.  Thanks! This appears to have solved the issue.