# Browser navigates but url cannot be matched in e2e test

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, protractor, e2e-testing

I am starting to learn e2e test with Protractor in our Angular app.
Now I am trying to test the routing in one of the pages.
All this should do is to spin up a page object and click on the top row of our test data with the id 7.
This (click)-Event triggers should trigger a routing event which takes me to the desired page.

forwarding.e2e-spec.ts

```
      let detailsPage: ForwardingDetailsPo;
      beforeAll(async () => {
        page = new ForwardingPagePo();
        await page.navigateTo();
        detailsPage = new ForwardingDetailsPo();
        table = await page.getForwardingTablePo();
        await table.getTable().getRow('7').click();
      });
      afterEach(async () => {
        await detailsPage.navigateTo('7');
      });
      it('should navigate to details', async (done) => {
        browser.getCurrentUrl().then(url => {
          expect(url).toContain('administration/forwardings/7');
          done();
          }
        );
      });

    });
```

After that I try to check if the url has changed.
The automatically opened browser, on which the tests are run seems to execute the task perfectly, yet the test fails:

`Expected 'http://localhost:4200/administration/forwardings' to contain 'administration/forwardings/7'.`

I already checked that the row I try to click `.isPresent()`.

As you can see I tryed to litter the code with awaits to avoid, that the test runs before the routing completes, but that does not seem to work perfectly.

Hints anyone?

**______EDIT_______**

The solution had nothing to do with the click itself, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you navigate to `7` after checking url not before, because `afterEach` executes after each `it` block

Comment: I should have mentioned, that the rows, do have click-event listeners which trigger the routing.
Thanks i edited the question.

Comment: do you have any setup for step-by-step debugging?

Comment: @RonaldHund ^ .

Comment: and the standard browser.pause() and browser.debugger() do not even trigger as of my observation

Comment: yeah... same here. I debug with webstorm, its free first month and then session is limited to 30 mins. And the license is cheap anyway. I recommend you install it and setup debugging configuration like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137109/how-to-debug-angular-protractor-tests-in-webstorm/53783055#53783055 it'll boost your ability of improving your tests. If I was dealing with your issue, this is how I would approach it, by executing step by step and seeing what's happening

Comment: hi i was able to hook my code up to the crome debugger, that was quite helpful indeed. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solutions and thought to share it here.
My problem was timing based.
I had some other tests that relied on BeforeEach functions to set up properly. In one of those I routed to my main page again. And since beforeAll gets executed before the beforeEach calls, the routing itself functioned like desired, but I was routing away practically immediatly.

Today I learned to not use beforeAll in some inner tests unless neccessary.